# Can C++17's deduced `auto` non-type `template` parameters pattern-match templates with explicit non-type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++17

Consider this example *([also available on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XI9W2GQa7DFLffOt))*:

```
template <template <auto> class>
void test() { }

template <int> 
struct X { };
```

Trying to instantiate `test<X>()` on `clang++` 4.0 *(trunk)* results in a compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'test'
     test<X>();
     ^~~~~~~

note: candidate template ignored: 
      invalid explicitly-specified argument for 1st template parameter
void test() { }
```

My initial assumption/intuition was that `test` could be used to match any `template` having a non-type parameter.

---

However, the following code snippet successfully compiles:

```
template <template <auto> class>
void test() { }

//        vvvv
template <auto> 
struct X { };
```

Is this intended? Could not find anything conclusive in [P0127R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html).

Comment: In the title, did you mean "deduced"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's definitely intended. Template-template parameters can only match templates which take the same kinds of arguments. This:

```
template <template <auto> class>
void test() { }
```

can only be instantiated with a class template that can take *any* kind of non-type parameter. But this:

```
template <int> 
struct X { };
```

is not such a class template. `X` can only be instantiated with an `int`. It simply does not match the specification for the template template parameter, hence the error. What if `test` wanted to instantiate its class template with a pointer type? Or pointer to function or pointer to member? That would be impossible.

Your second attempt, with `template <auto> struct X { };` *does* match the template-template parameter, hence is well-formed. Note also that the reverse, having `test` take a `template <int> class` parameter and passing in `template <auto> struct X { };` is also well-formed as the argument is more general than the parameter.

---

The relevant wording is in [temp.arg.template]:

> A *template-argument* matches a template *template-parameter* `P` when each of the template parameters in the *template-parameter-list* of the *template-argument*’s corresponding class template or alias template `A` matches
>   the corresponding template parameter in the *template-parameter-list* of `P`. Two template parameters match if they are of the same kind (type, non-type, template), for non-type *template-parameters*, their types are
>   equivalent (14.5.6.1), and for template *template-parameters*, each of their corresponding *template-parameters* matches, recursively.

---

Note: the equivalence wording accepts the `auto` - `auto` case and rejects the `auto` - `int` case, but also seems to reject the `int` - `auto` case (based on my reading). I'm going to try to get some clarification on it.

Comment: Any result for your clarification request?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb [nope](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/xVUfSpP0_48)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Barry's answer, which made me curious, here are the four possible combinations and results using Clang 4.0 (SVN), [*see also on wandbox*](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gCk2Dny2LraYJYIZ):

```
template <bool> struct obj_bool { };  // object taking a value of boolean type
template <auto> struct obj_auto { };  // object taking a value of deduced type
//       ^^^^^^ Note: this is a template value argument (non-type template argument)

template <template <auto> typename> void fn_auto() { }
template <template <bool> typename> void fn_bool() { }
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Note: this is a template type argument
//                 ^^^^^^                taking a template value argument

int main() {     
    fn_bool<obj_bool>();    // #1 bool->bool OK (exact match)
    fn_auto<obj_auto>();    // #2 auto->auto OK (exact match)
    fn_bool<obj_auto>();    // #3 bool->auto OK (sub-set)
    //fn_auto<obj_bool>();  // #4 auto->bool Error: no matching function.
}
```

From that, #1 and #2 are obviously exact matches and are working as expected. #3 would invoke the bool implementation on a template that can handle not only bool but all types, whereas #4 would try to invoke a definition expecting a generalized object (auto) with an object providing only a sub-set (bool) of possibilities.

The templated function `fn_auto` promises possible instantiations for templates taking any value type (auto). Thus giving it only a sub-set of possibilities (bool) violates this promise.

Though not immediately obvious, the restriction makes sense. And sorry for my wording not being C++ Standard compliant.